# Play: Managing library dependencies within IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, slick

I'm trying to configure play-slick within IntelliJ IDEA. I added the following statement to build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "1.1.1"
```

the download seems to work fine however I don't see `Slick`in "External Libraries" section (I do see `com.typesafe.slick` in `.ivi2/cache/` folder, but that seems external to IntelliJ). How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, SBT keeps dependencies in general local repository, not in the instance, thanks to this you can reuse same downloaded libs in many projects. If IntelliJ doesn't recognize the path, try to clear the cache and/or restart Idea. it usually takes several seconds to start recognizing updated libs, but sometimes it just stacks for a bit longer.